# Does $\mathrm A \mathrm A^T \succeq x^2 \mathrm I$ imply $\frac{\mathrm A + \mathrm A^T}{2} \succeq x \mathrm I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $A $ be an $n \times n $ matrix such that $AA^T \geq x^2I, x\geq 0 $, which means that the matrix  $AA^T-x^2I$ is positive semidefinite. Can we show that $(A+A^T)/2 \geq xI$?

Thanks

Comment: You made a sign error in the first sentence. (Either $A A^T \leq x^2 I$ or $A A^T - x^2 I$ is positive semidefinite. Either way is fine, but what you wrote isn't consistent with standard notation.)

Comment: Maybe you mean that $ AA^T-x^2I$ is positive semidefinite

Comment: Why is it not consistent? What do you mean by consistent?

Comment: However I think that the statement should be reformulated, because as it is, it is trivially false simply because of the sign of $x$. Infact, assume $A$ to be simply a one-by-one matrix, then you say that if $A^2\geq x^2$, then $A\geq x$

Comment: $x $ is nonnegative real number.

Comment: @Zhale For symmetric matrices $A,B$, $A \geq B$ means $A-B$ is positive semidefinite. This matches up with the order on real numbers when you look at just one dimension. Sometimes we use a different symbol to avoid confusion with the usual real number $\leq$.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$\mathrm A := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Then,

$$\mathrm A \mathrm A^T = \mathrm A^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm I_2$$

However,

$$\frac{\mathrm A + \mathrm A^T}{2} = \mathrm A \preceq I_2$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you know what assumption is needed in order to have the desired inequality?

Comment: @Zhale  At least the converse is true (i.e., $A+A^\dagger\succeq 2x\,I$ and $x\geq 0$ implies that $AA^\dagger\succeq x^2I$).